# Session in api-functional tests isLoggedIn always returns false

Tags: magento-2.1, rest-api, session, testing, api-functional-tests

I have a function in an API call that checks `$this->session->isLoggedIn()`.

The session-object is injected via the consturtor.

Now I have to write an api-functional test. But I just can't login the customer and `isLoggedIn()` will always return `false` in my service. My test-code currently looks like this:

```
    $historyId = 1;
    $download = 0;

    $serviceInfo = [
        'rest' => [
            'resourcePath' => '/V1/preorder-history/view/' . $historyId . '/' . $download,
            'httpMethod' => \Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Request::HTTP_METHOD_GET,
        ]
    ];

    $loginInfo = [
        'rest' => [
            'resourcePath' => '/V1/customers/me',
            'httpMethod' => \Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Request::HTTP_METHOD_GET,
            'token' => $this->token,
        ],
    ];

    $requestData = [
        'historyId' => $historyId,
        'download' => $download,
        'token' => $this->token
    ];

    $customer = $this->_webApiCall($loginInfo, $requestData);

    /** @var $session \Magento\Customer\Model\Session */
    $session = Bootstrap::getObjectManager()->get(\Magento\Customer\Model\Session::class);
    $session->loginById($customer['id']);
    $session->setCustomerId($customer['id']);

    $item = $this->_webApiCall($serviceInfo, $requestData);
```

## EDIT:

within my test, the session object obviously returns that the customer is logged in. So I assume this is not the same object that is injected in my service which I want to test.

## EDIT2:

`spl_object_hash` confirms this theory.

Answer (score 1):

The API functional tests are black box tests, you cannot change the application state within the tests. Use the API login method instead.

This is a method that you can use in your test:

```
private function apiLogin($username, $password)
{
    $serviceInfo = [
        'rest' => [
            'resourcePath' => "/V1/integration/customer/token",
            'httpMethod' => \Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Request::HTTP_METHOD_POST,
        ],
    ];
    $requestData = ['username' => $username, 'password' => $password];
    $this->token = $this->_webApiCall($serviceInfo, $requestData);
}
```

Then use `'token' => $this->token,` in your subsequent API calls, as you already do.

Comment: "Use the API login method instead" could you elaborate that?

Comment: @PhilippSander you can see an example here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/dev/tests/api-functional/testsuite/Magento/Customer/Api/AccountManagementMeTest.php#L325 I'll update my answer with details

Comment: thanks for your update, but that's exactly what I do right now. sorry that I didn't post the code.

Comment: Then what are these lines supposed to do? `$session = Bootstrap::getObjectManager()->get(\Magento\Customer\Model\Session::class);
    $session->loginById($customer['id']);
    $session->setCustomerId($customer['id']);` - can you remove them and update the question with the whole relevant code?

Comment: they are an attempt to solve my problem. deleteing them will still result in session->isLoggedIn() returning false in my service.